# Align output in python to the right using %

Tags: python

My code will produce an output that will be right-aligned. This is the code:

```
star = '*'
n = 0
while star:
    n = n+1
    fmt = "{:>{size}s}"
    print fmt.format(star*n, size=10)
    if n > 9:
         break
```

And the output is:

```
         *
        **
       ***
      ****
     *****
    ******
   *******
  ********
 *********
**********
```

How do I change if I want to use "%10s" instead of this?:

```
fmt = "{:>{size}s}"
print fmt.format(star*n, size=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the `<` sign for left aligned text with new style formatting:

```
fmt = "{:<{size}s}".format(star*n, size=10)
```

Here's the weird equivalent that old style formatting provides:

```
fmt = "%-*s" % (10, star*n)

>>> "%*s" % (10, "***")
'       ***'
>>> "%-*s" % (10, "***")
'***       '
```

Comment: @jamylak sorry I've changed it in the question. What I meant is, how do I use % sign instead of using fmt = "{:>{size}s}"?

Comment: @jamylak well I'm just curious on how to do it